# 7 bit ascii with icu4j

Tags: java, ascii, icu

I'n trying to use icu4j library. I want to receive a text, determine an encoding and then to convert it into 7 bit ascii format i.e. to use &#number instead of a symbol from extended ascii table (whose value is greater than 128).

for detecting an encoding a create a CharsetDetector and than apply a method detect(). 
But I can not find anything to convert to 7 bit ascii. Do you know may be how I can do it using icu?

thank you in advance.

UPD. Actually I cannot understand how to convert with this library. I use

```
 CharsetDetector cd = new CharsetDetector();
 String str = cd.getString(myStr, encoding);
```

trying to write different things instead of encoding, but it always offers me UTF-8 representation of the string.

Comment: Why? what is the problem you're trying to solve by using 7bit clean ascii that still requires you to encode non-ascii characters? It sounds a little like you're asking about an XY problem -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: to have a clean HTML file

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Encode your data as UTf8 unicode to .html file and make sure to add the HTML markup `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the head, so that browsers know how to decode the bytes. Done. We solved that problem over a decade ago, don't reintroduce by coming up with funky encodings. Use UTF8 for your HTML files, and everyone will be much happier.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans has the best recommendation.   And a nit: if the high bit is set (greater than or equal to 128), it's not `US-ASCII`.